# npm webpack: coomand not found

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm running this command on linux:

> sudo npm install -g webpack

I'm getting the following output:

> /home/igor/.npm-global/bin/webpack ->
>   /home/igor/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
>   /home/igor/.npm-global/lib └── webpack@1.13.3

which looks perfectly legit, but when I try to use:

> webpack -h

I get the

> webpack: command not found

How can I make webpack running from the command prompt?

Comment: How did you install your Node.js? Tell us your Node & NPM version.

Comment: npm version 3.10.8 node 6.8.1. Guess, I downloaded the binaries and then updated

Comment: Global packages are usually installed into `/usr/local/bin/` not in your Home. Did you change it with `~/.npmrc`?

Comment: @goenning no, I did not. btw, which node shows /usr/bin/node

Comment: If you add `/home/igor/.npm-global/bin/` to your PATH it'll probably work for webpack and other modules you install. But that's odd, it's not the default folder.

Comment: what's the best option?

Comment: You probably followed this tutorial https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions at some point and changed the default folder. Append `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH` to your `~/.profile`.

Comment: @goenning It worked. May I have your answer, please. Please, make it more detailed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default directory for globally installed NPM modules is `/usr/local`, which will install the module binaries inside `bin` folder. 
If you echo your $PATH environment variable you'll see that `/usr/local/bin` is in your path. That means when you run a command like `webpack`, macOS will try to find the binary in this folder or any other folder on your $PATH.

At some point you probably changed it to `~/.npm-global`, which installed `webpack` binary into your `/home/igor/.npm-global/bin/`. As this folder is not in you $PATH, macOS did not find it. You can run `npm config get prefix` to confirm this.

Solution 1 is to add it to your path by changing your `~/.profile` file. Just append `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH` to it and restart your terminal.

Solution 2 is to change back the default folder to `/usr/local` by running `npm config set prefix '/usr/local'`. In this case you won't need to change your PATH variable.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install webpack localy on the path you're working with.